# Bound Textboxes (to Datagridview) not reflecting the bound data if Date is either today or in the past

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a bound DataGridView and I've bound textboxes and a DateTimePicker to that DGV.

Everything is working perfectly, the textboxes are reflecting the data as the DGV row is selected, *unless* the Date in one of the DGV columns is either today or in the past. In that case, the textboxes act as though they're not bound at all...until a new DGV row is selected with a future date, and then the textboxes work as normal again.

Here's my textbox bindings:

```
    txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", iBS, "Contact")
    txtEmail.DataBindings.Add("Text", iBS, "Email")
    txtNotes.DataBindings.Add("Text", iBS, "Notes")
    dtpDate.DataBindings.Add("Text", iBS, "xDate")
```

Comment: If you exclude the `DateTimePicker` from binding, do you still see the same behaviour?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Hey! I know you from the forums! I haven't tried that, but if I click on a row in my DGV with a date in the future, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: _the textboxes act as though they're not bound at all_ - what yo mean? Does textboxes become empty, or texboxes still display values of previously selected row or else?

Comment: Hey - the text boxes still display values of a previously selected row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out why.

On FormLoad, I put DateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Now. This is causing the problem. Removing that line completely removes this issue.